# Pass Data From View to Controller Returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

Hi I'm trying to pass an ID number from View to a Controller. For some reason ID comes back as 0 and I'm not sure why?

Here is my code for View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Update", "Create", "Response", new { id=item.LogID }, null)
```

In my Controller is:

```
int LogID;


[Authorize(Roles = "Customer")]
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
{
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        LogID = id.Value;
    }

    return View();
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Response response)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        response.DateTimeOfUpdate = System.DateTime.Now;
        response.LogID = LogID;
        db.Responses.Add(response);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Log", new { area = "" });
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged to check if the value is actually correct in the view?

Comment: I should say the value is actually 0 and not null. Yes

Comment: Does `item.LogID` have a value? What URL does `Html.ActionLink` produce?

Comment: The ActionLink links to Create method which produces another View

Comment: The LogID(item.LogID) appears on the page as it should be but for some reason it passes in 0

Comment: URL is http://localhost:62165/Response/Create/400012 as correct

Comment: This produces the correct ID. It outputs to console ' System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(id.Value);'

Comment: You are trying to call the `public ActionResult Create(int? id)` action?

Comment: Yes that is the correct method